# Process Builder missing equals sign?

Tags: formula, error, process, compile-error, builder

In Process Builder, I am writing a formula for a field value. I would like it to look at a newly created attendee record's preferred email field, see if the contents of that field match the email field of existing contact records, and, if so, write the first and last name of that contact into the contact field of the attendee record. When I try to save the formula below, I get this error message: "The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='"

```
IF( [EventApi__Attendee__c].[EventApi__Preferred_Email__c] = [EventApi__Contact__c].Email, [EventApi__Contact__c].FirstName + " " + [EventApi__Contact__c].LastName, "no match found" )
```

Any tips on getting past the error message and getting the formula to work?

Answer (score 4):

`String` concatenation in a formula use the `&` character instead of the `+`.

```
IF( [EventApi__Attendee__c].[EventApi__Preferred_Email__c] = [EventApi__Contact__c].Email, [EventApi__Contact__c].FirstName & " " & [EventApi__Contact__c].LastName, "no match found" )
```

Comment: Made recommended modification and received same error message.

Comment: Did you try `[EventApi__Attendee__c].EventApi__Preferred_Email__c` instead of `[EventApi__Attendee__c].[EventApi__Preferred_Email__c]`?

Comment: Recommended modification resulted in no longer receiving the same error message--thank you @MartinLezer. Interestingly, the new error message is a bit strange. **The formula expression is invalid: Field Attendee.Email does not exist. Check spelling.**